# how to get woocommerce product id by acf field in wordpress and display product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

```
$product_cat_object = get_queried_object();
        $axy = get_field('select_artists', 'product_cat_' . $product_cat_object->term_id);  

       $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
            'terms'    => array(var_dump($axy) ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: `var_dump()` is not the right function to use there. It prints information about  the variable and doesn't return anything.

Comment: Can you please explain how `ACF field`, `product_cat` and `product` are linked with each other, with respect to your query? I'm confused with the question.

Answer (score -1):

Use only `$axy` instead of `'terms' => array(var_dump($axy) ), ...`
It will work, surly. Try it.

```
        'terms' => $axy,
```